# Raw keys (RSA, AES) generation vs SSL/TLS performance

Tags: ssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, aes, rsa

I am working on a small project that aims to design a secure communication between two, or more, devices A and B, with the following limitations:

- Device A has very limited resources (e.g, smart card).
- The used communication should perform minimum number of encryption/decryption operations to establish a secure connection.
- Bidirectional authentication is required, in which A should be 100% sure of B's identity and vice versa.
- The used technique should use public key cryptography (e.g., RSA) and after that establish a shared key using symmetric algorithm (e.g., AES)

I know that using certificates is much easier to manage and use. However, due to the limitations I though of using predefined RSA keys for both of the entities and afterward the devices can negotiate the new shared key using AES.

My question is about the validity of such technique and would it have better performance than using SSL/TLS certificates; in terms of number of steps and resources usage. Moreover, it would be really helpful if someone have numerical analysis for using raw keys generation (as my example above) versus using SSL/TLS certificates.

Comment: Please update your and add details on `Device A has very limited resources` because it is ambiguous. "Limited resources" are relative, e.g. for some people a Raspberry is limited, others would call Bluetooth beacon, a smartcard limited?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is about the validity of such technique and would it have better performance than using SSL/TLS certificates

Parsing certificates is tricky because it has a lot of ifs/elses, but even embedded CPU's would be able to do this. If you fully want to parse certificates you could also look at "card verifiable certificates" which are relatively simplistic certificates created for verification on smart cards (with similarly limited resources such as 8-10 KiB RAM, or less).

Besides that, verification is a (relatively efficient) RSA verification operation. You can however avoid this by simply pinning the certificate from B. You could for instance simply test the certificate by calculating the certificate fingerprint by performing a cryptographic hash, which you stored before.

As for the key generation: it won't of course matter for the RSA key pair generation itself. For the master secret agreement (and then session key derivation) TLS has multiple options such as using key agreement of the master secret + RSA authentication or RSA encryption of the master secret. How it compares to your scheme depends on the proprietary protocol.

There are of course also symmetric options available for TLS such as PSK (pre-shared key) and SRP. This will also create session keys, but both devices have hold only one shared key (or other token).

---

TLS has many options and doesn't *necessarily* introduce too much overhead. The problem is that if you try and create your own protocol you're bound to fail. With your current knowledge failure is almost certain. So I'd consider (variations) of TLS before exploring anything else. If you're up to it you can consider high performance suites such as Chacha20+Poly1305, possibly even paired with a Curve25519 self signed certificate.